# how to extract rows by comparing data value and categories in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

```
1320    A   2010    455
1325    B   2010    52
1336    A   2011    148
1341    B   2011    37
1352    A   2012    57
1357    B   2012    8
```

I'd like to get result of difference between two groups in the same year, like

```
1 2010 403
2 2011 111
3 2012 49
```

Currently, i just shift dataframe and make subtraction, but obviously it will only work on clean formatted data. I'd like to know how to get a way to do this subtraction by checking year and group id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['group'] = ['A','B']*3
df['year'] = [2010,2010,2011,2011,2012,2012]
df['value'] = [455,52,148,37,57,8]

df.loc[df.group=='B','value']*=-1

dfNew = df.groupby('year').sum()

print dfNew
```

If we start with **df**:

```
  group  year  value
0     A  2010    455
1     B  2010     52
2     A  2011    148
3     B  2011     37
4     A  2012     57
5     B  2012      8
```

We get **dfNew**:

```
      value
year       
2010    403
2011    111
2012     49
```